# line equation in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have the equation:

$$ax + by + c = 0$$

The exercise asks me to pass this equation to polar coordinates. What I tried:

$$x = r\cos\theta, y + r\sin\theta$$

then we should have:

$$ar\cos\theta + br\sin\theta + c = 0$$

Is this all I have to do? I don't see a way to proceed in this conversion. Therefore I think I'm done. Am I rigth?

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes it is wished to solve for r if possible. Like to write r as a function of theta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without numerical values, you can't go very far.

However, the standard form of a line equation in polar coordinates expresses the fact that the projection of any point of the line onto the perpendicular line through the origin is constant. If $\theta_0$ is the polar angle of that normal, the equation can be written as:
$$r\cos(\theta-\theta_0)=C.$$
Thus you first rewrite the cartesian equation as
$$\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} r\cos \theta+\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}r\sin \theta +\frac c{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=0$$

then solve for the system:
$$\cos \theta_0=\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\quad \sin\theta_0=\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
ang you'll get the standard form.